# How to specify map properties in Struts 2 JSON Plugin

Tags: json, dictionary, struts2

I'm using Struts 2 along with the json plugin, the properties mappings in the struts.xml file are typically frustrating but I am able to figure them out.

I have come across a case where I cannot set the includeProperties to give me the result I expect.

Frequently I use a configuration expression

```
^itemList\[\d+\]\.id,
^itemList\[\d+\]\.name
....
```

This works well.

In this case I would like to return data from a Map not a list (or a map that's a child of a list member)

If a * is used the whole map is printed out correctly, but I do not want all the data from the map elements.

```
^itemList\[\d+\]\map\.*
```

The whole map is returnd

I have tried several different formats and none of them have produced results.

```
^itemList\[\d+\]\map\[\d+\]\.id
^itemList\[\d+\]\map\[\d+\]\.name
```

Nothing is returned in the map property

Anyone had any luck with a syntax to restrict the contents of a map?

Thanks
-Scott

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use 'd' it map as integer.
Try this `^itemList\..*$`

Answer (score 0):

1) Your regular expression is suspicious. Note that in the expression "^itemList[\d+]\map[\d+].id", +d refers to one more more digits, so the map would have to have digit(s) as it's key. If this is not what you want, then '.+' is probably more appropriate (one or more of any character).

2) Convert the Map to a LinkedHashMap and then treat it as a list. (Have not tested this, it might not work)

Comment: I did make a couple of mistakes in the expressions, missed a couple of '.' but you are correct the +d is looking for a number.

I tried a couple of iterations of other expressions to represent the string key of the Map, nothing I tried worked.

At this point I have created a lightweight object that I am populating to represent the data in my map, this was the most functional approach. It required an additional class and moved some of the configuration to a different point in the application, but it produced the best result for my purpose.